# How to select certain table in my database

Tags: sql, database, select, oledb

I'm currently using OleDB.

My problem is I can't select my table when searching it using textbox.

This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand inv = new OleDbCommand("Select [Part Number], [Part Name], [Ordered Quantity], [Arrived Quantity] From '"+textBox1.Text+"%'", PartsDB);
OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(inv);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapt.Fill(dt);
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: This is a SQL Injection Vulnerability, don't do this.  Which database are you using? MYSQL, SQL SERVER, Oracle, etc?

Comment: Also: which programming language is that?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection concerns aside this is not valid SQL. You are trying to make your table name 1) a string and 2) wild carded. This is not supported by any variant of SQL that I am aware of.

i.e.

```
Select column1, column2 From 'Tablename%'
```

is not valid SQL. You must say...

```
Select column1, column2 From Tablename
```

where Tablename exists as a table in your database

Answer (score 0):

What is it that makes you have several ***distinct*** tables in your database that you should be able to do that same SELECT from ?

In principle, if you have that situation, then there must be some information element that distinguishes those tables from one another, and the intent of the relational model is for such tables to be combined into one, with the distinguishing element included as an additional attribute (/column).